# fonts and content used for what app ticker icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Which type of fonts and content used for whats app ticker icon?

I am using bootstrap glyphicons ( `.glyphicon-remove:before {content: "\2715";}` & `.glyphicon-ok:before {content: "\e013"; }`).

But the tick mark is not appropriate to my requirement.

Whats app ticker icon will be suitable to my requirement.
Could you give me some guidance how to achieve the ticker icon

Comment: you mean double ticker..

Answer (score 0):

Check [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), they do have a Whats App icon and a bunch of more, hopefully you'll find what you are searching for.

Comment: I have gone thru the site which you have provided. That is not useful to my requirement.